# Special character indexing

Tags: special-characters, lucene

i am creating a Lucene 3.0.3 index using **StandardAnalyzer**.

when searching is made on index using query like **C**, **C#** or **C++** it gives same result for all these three term. As, i know while creating index analyzer ignore special character and do not create index for same.

**Need to be able to differentiate between "C", "C#" and "C++"**

please suggest me that, Is any existing analyzer will resolve this issue?

Any suggestion will be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 3):

I guess that happens because of the fact that `StandardAnalyzer` uses `StandardFilter`, which uses `StandardTokenizer`, which removes special characters.
You could create your own Analyzer implementation.

Comment: how i can use KeywordAnalyzer along with existing StandardAnalyzer?    any idea!!

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/lucene/java-user/91747?do=post_view_threaded#91747